# Obtener valor de checkbox seleccionados con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una pequeña función que recorre todos los checkbox y muestra el valor de los que han sido seleccionados.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
        //cada elemento seleccionado
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

**¿Como podría almacenar en variables los valores por separado?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar una combinación de la función map para obtener estos valores en un arreglo, o en una cadena, donde cada valor estaría separado por coma.

Te paso un ejemplo, espero que te ayude:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('[name="checks[]"]').click(function() {
      
    var arr = $('[name="checks[]"]:checked').map(function(){
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    
    var str = arr.join(',');
    
    $('#arr').text(JSON.stringify(arr));
    
    $('#str').text(str);
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 200px">
  <ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li><input name="checks[]" type="checkbox" value="0" /></li>
    <li><input name="checks[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></li>
    <li><input name="checks[]" type="checkbox" value="2" /></li>
    <li><input name="checks[]" type="checkbox" value="3" /></li>
    <li><input name="checks[]" type="checkbox" value="4" /></li>
    <li><input name="checks[]" type="checkbox" value="5" /></li>
    <li><input name="checks[]" type="checkbox" value="6" /></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div >Ids seleccionados en matriz <span id="arr"></span></div>
  <div >Ids seleccionados <span id="str"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes crearte un array con los valores de los checks, asi:

```
let valoresCheck = [];

$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
    valoresCheck.push(this.value);
});
```

Los valores quedaran guardados en el array.

---

**EDICION**:
Si **realmente** necesitas crear una variable independiente por cada uno de los inputs, podes hacerlo accediendo al objeto `window` y creando dinamicamente las variables, (no recomiendo hacer esto, es altamente confuso y poco practico)

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index, check ){
    window["valorInput"+index] = check.value;
});
```

Esto creara una sucesion de variables en el scope global llamadas valorInputN yendo del 0 a la cantidad de inputs que haya. Espero que sirva de algo.

Comment: Como podría almacenar en una variable cada valor?

Comment: @arglez35 Edite mi respuesta, espero te sea util ese metodo

Comment: que me recomiendas si lo que necesito hacer es guardar el valor de cada checbox para enviarlo por post en ajax y generar una consulta en php?

Comment: Lo que recomiendo es la aproximacion del array, este se puede mandar como parametro para la request de ajax. Si eso es realmente lo que necesitas te recomendaria que modifiques tu pregunta para que exprese mejor tu problema